# 2003 Acura tl overheating

Tags: overheating, acura

Hello I have a 2003 Acura tl 3.2 liter and the temperature keep going up towards the hot side of the gauge and I ch the thermostat and filled the coolant and it doesn't do it all the time so what could it be? Please help

Comment: Have you read the other questions here on overheating? The usual suspects have been covered extensively.

Answer (score 1):

We really need more information to drill down your particular issue.

Overheating indicates that the cooling system is not able to transfer heat from the engine to the surroundings. This could be due to several reasons:

- A stuck-closed thermostat that doesn't allow the coolant to flow as much as it needs to.
- A radiator fan that isn't running the way it should. If the fan is electric, a break in the connection or burnt fuse may be to blame. There could also be a mechanical problem with the fan if it doesn't spin freely.
- Low coolant flow, which could indicate a clogged water pump or clogged coolant piping.